# Folder owner and LocalSystem

Tags: .net, permissions

I'm currently coding a .net windows service, and I need to store confidential data in a folder. I have to modify the folder's security, to make its owner and authorizations granted to LocalSystem, and deny access to user. I don't know anything about .net security class, and I didn't find anything on the web about LocalSystem (all the examples require a username)

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you utilize any folder and encrypt the data using an user´s supplied password or a system random one?  Wouldn´t be more secure?

Comment: My application has to process this data before using it realtime, encryption/decryption will slow the process, so I cannot do it this way

Comment: If you utilize the AES from .NET Cryptography library and, depending of the quantity of bytes, the operation may require less than 1 second. You may store it in MappedFiles (or an Array/List) before write it (encrypted) to disk.